# Dark Mode glitch on Vivo v23 Pro

Tags: android-12, vivo, dark-mode

Why is the Dark mode in my Vivo v23 pro like this? It's bit transparent in darker areas, I'm able to see my phone's background and icons. Its very weird. Any solutions?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a burnt-in screen to me.

Comment: Is it? Any solutions?

Comment: @SayanManna try screen burning a white image

Answer (score 0):

That's a display defect. This forum is mostly intended for software support.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/252111)